# How to inject asp.net mvc areas

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, git, nuget, scale

I have a traditional `asp.net mvc` application. I have two teams who will work on the application and manage view controllers and models under separate MVC areas. Teams will have a different release cadence so I'd like those team's to use separate GIT repositories from the main application, and have the main application pull in content via NuGet packages.

I thought this would be a common problem, but I have not found much guidance on the net. I guess I'm looking for the `.net` equivalent of a JavaScript micro frontend.

What `.net` pattern/framework should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be with a Razor Class Library, see Microsoft docs for more on this [Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Essentially you could have each library in a separate git repo as you have requested. Each library would sit in its own area in your main app and you could override the library views locally if you wish. As far as the docs go each RCL is typically built up of Razor Pages. However, I have heard of teams using MVC inside the RCL instead, it would require a bit more work though. Struggling to find docs on this though.